# Flex menu on more rows without lonely last element?

Tags: html, css, menu, flexbox

Easy row menu with flex. In some viewport width (~600px) is menu splited with one lonely element on own second row. How to split that menu better?

Screenshot:

[image: Flex menu with too long last element]

"Better" means for example 4 elements on first row and 3 elements on second row. Or 5 element on first row and 2 elements on second row. Just not this 6:1.

Here is my [code](https://codepen.io/kelv/pen/YEgmjP)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: Georgia, serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #a0522d;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 75em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: helvetica;
  padding: 0
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /*max-width:16rem*/
}

ul li a {
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.313em;
  background: PaleGoldenrod;
  margin: 0.063em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="content">
  <li><a href="#">Site name</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Next link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Something else</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Almost last link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Last link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Code: https://codepen.io/kelv/pen/YEgmjP

Answer (score 2):

You may use media query and change the flex propery of the elements like this :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: Georgia, serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #a0522d;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 75em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: helvetica;
  padding: 0
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

ul li a {
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.313em;
  background: PaleGoldenrod;
  margin: 0.063em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media all and (max-width:620px) {
  ul li {
    flex: 0 0 25%;
  }
  ul li:nth-child(n+5) {
    flex: 0 0 33%;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width:500px) {
  ul li:nth-child(n) {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
  ul li:last-child{
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width:320px) {
  ul li:nth-child(n) {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="content">
  <li><a href="#">Site name</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Next link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Something else</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Almost last link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Last link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Another solution if you can change your HTML structure is to divide the menu into two `ul` like this :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: Georgia, serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #a0522d;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.menu .content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 75em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: helvetica;
  padding: 0
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width:120px;
}

ul li a {
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.313em;
  background: PaleGoldenrod;
  margin: 0.063em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="content">
    <li><a href="#">Site name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Next link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="content">
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Almost last link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Last link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but:
1) This solution has lonely element too. In viewport width 931px - 935px.

2) Solution should be for different width of elements (width by text). Not set one with for all of them. It makes columns, not nice brick wall ;).

Comment: @MartinMilichovský in the snippet here ?

Comment: @MartinMilichovský you can increase the max-width of media query if need ... but i don't see any lonely element between 931-935 ... are you using more CSS ?

Comment: @MartinMilichovský ok i see, are you able to change the HTML Structure ?

Comment: "in the snippet here ?  "
Yes: http://s.kelv.cz/flex/flex-menu-last-too-long-2.png

Comment: "ok i see, are you able to change the HTML Structure ? "


I can. I am looking for common solution for flex menu with different width of elements. Menu with common structure <ul><li><li></ul>

Comment: @MartinMilichovský ok so check my second solution ;)

Comment: @MartinMilichovský and it's very strange that my snippet behave like this for you, am not able to reproduce it

Comment: And same width of element is not requested. Columns looks worst then bricks (different width of elements).

http://s.kelv.cz/flex/flex-menu-last-not-columns-4.png

Comment: @MartinMilichovský you may add a min-width also .. check again the last solution

Comment: @MartinMilichovský _Temani_ have showed how you can control the wrap and element size using media query's. With this you can now create any brick like solution you wish, so simply accept this answer and start using what's learned from it. And do note, an answer must not create an _exact_ result to be accepted, and as you asked for _"Just not this 6:1"_, this does exactly that.

Comment: Nice trick with two ULs, but http://s.kelv.cz/flex/flex-menu-middle-too-long.png :(. 

And many CMS make only one UL in menu.

Comment: @MartinMilichovský unfortunately you cannot have a generic solution since you menu depend on its content, so the only way is to consider media-query and adjust values depending on the content. Am sure your menu will not change every day

Comment: It is for template. Can be used on many websites, not only one menu.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using `flex-basis` combined with media queries to achieve the desired result, the `flex-basis` values can be changed based on your requirement!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: Georgia, serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #a0522d;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 75em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: helvetica;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /*max-width:16rem*/
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

ul li a {
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0.2em 0.2em;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.313em;
  background: PaleGoldenrod;
  margin: 0.063em;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 630px) {
  ul li {
    flex-basis: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="content">
  <li><a href="#">Site name</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Next link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Something else</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Almost last link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Last link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @MartinMilichovský Corrected it!

Comment: Words on more lines in element make unnecessarily height :(   http://s.kelv.cz/flex/flex-menu-last-words-wrap.png

Comment: @MartinMilichovský Reduce the font size, there are also other CSS fixes for this, but using the method in the question you can achieve the row layout you need!

Comment: Looking for common solution with differerent width of words and different font settings.

Comment: @MartinMilichovský Just see my reasoning, if text is larger than the container, obviously the text will collapse so that the contents can be seen by the user, if the text does not collapse, then the text will come out of the container(overflow) which will look really ugly, so the generic solution is a compromise between the font-size or any other css, to adjust the text to fit the container!

Comment: It is for template. Can be used on many websites, not only one menu with this text.

Comment: @MartinMilichovský All the best!